# Raspberry Pi; blank desktop

Tags: pi-2

I have two raspberry pi 2 boards. I have wrote raspbian wheezy image on 8GB card using win32DiskImager.
But whenever I run my board, nothing appear on the desktop connected (hdmi to VGA converter used)

Tried by replacing sd card or pi board also, rewrite image several times. Checked for solid +5V supply by CRO. Nothing shows up on desktop. Downloaded image again & tried it also. Not working

However I have a old SPI based TFT image, when i write this image & boot pi.; screen appears. But since its a TFT image, on scrren I see Pi booting up, but then it stops on message "fps = 50 ****". something like that. Since pi will now show data on TFT. I don't have TFT now, so I cannot see data.

Whenever I use TFt image, I see something on screen, that means pi is working & all HDMi & desktop is oK.
But as soon as I write wheezy image, nothing appears.

Comment: are you sure that the HDMI to VGA adapter is working. Can you try using a regular HDMI cable to a monitor or TV or barring that the composite video output? Also have you tried Jesse?

Comment: try to access using Putty and xming server [visit](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjczouZy7_JAhWSCI4KHYJEAnMQtwIIJjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBCXxPqCANBo&usg=AFQjCNGds9E_d-VzNoPCgV6ilvIrsW5KVQ&bvm=bv.108538919,d.c2E)

Comment: You can try accessing the raspberry pi over serial port

Comment: Have you tried installing the OS to the SD card using NOOBS?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I must suggest you to use raspbian buster.
Then I think you have a problem with your HDMI cable ,same as me.
Assume you are using latest release of raspberry pi then you don't have to play with /boot/config.txt. Change the cable and OS both.

Answer (score 0):

I have loaded Jessie today & its working. Now I can desktop screen.
Strange I rewrote the card with wheezy image(fresh downloaded from internet) & its not working again. Same problem. 
Loading jessie again works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the recommended build for RPi2 is Jessie, not wheezy.

Answer (score -1):

Two days ago I started using jessie and had same problem like you do but I did not check it with SPI Display.

I did check config.txt and used the last setting that I used when the OS was still wheezy. It works.

I remember I followed this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=5851&p=77547#p77547.
you need to set up the mode and group as in this :
    # uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
    hdmi_group=2
    hdmi_mode=39
    # uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
    # DMT (computer monitor) modes
    hdmi_drive=2